# What database or storage engine to use for storing many unique items?

Tags: database, storage

I'm considering writing a web crawler that just collects URLs of pages and nothing more (for an archiving project), but I have issues in finding a proper way to store the results.

The requirements are that whatever storage engine is used, can handle hundreds of thousands of items (preferably with the ability to add metadata to each entry, although not required), and that existing items can be ignored (so as to avoid duplicates) without a significant performance hit.

The engines I've looked at:

- **MySQL**: Becomes significantly slower in checking for existing items as the database grows larger.
- **SQLite**: Same problem as above, even worse performance hits.
- **memcache and Redis**: The dataset may become large enough to make RAM storage infeasible.
- **MongoDB**: Not sure if performance will be acceptable if the majority of the dataset is stored on disk, based on the [explanation on their website](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/fundamentals/#does-mongodb-require-a-lot-of-ram).

What are your thoughts on the suitability of MongoDB (as I have no experience with working with large datasets in MongoDB), and are you aware of any better (free) storage engines existing for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a NoSQL solution would suit you well.

Especially since you just want somewhere to dump a variety of flexible data under an "id" of the URL.

I've used lucene, but mongo is a good choice too.

Comment: Would MongoDB not give issues with large datasets on a machine with little RAM? I don't know the specifics of MongoDB, but recall something about it (mostly?) running from RAM.

Comment: How little RAM are we talking about?

Comment: That is ample to run a nosql database

Answer (score 1):

If you use a traditional RDBMS, you could create a unique key based on the hash of your data (eg: hash the URL with md5 or sha1). That will keep the unique key small(ish), and should help performance.

I like PostgreSQL - you might want to do some tests with that.

*Edit: (see comments)* Ok, maybe avoid md5 in this day and age (:

Comment: +1. A complete industry is based on such an idea (data deduplication). But please not MD5.

Comment: @dmeister What would you recommend for hashing?

Comment: SHA-256 should be a good choice. MD5 simply can create trouble because I can easily calculate hash collisions. This can can cause problems (data loss, security) is certain situations. While hash collisions are still possible with SHA-256, they are not able to generate on purpose (2012) and are very, very, very unlikely to happen by accident (birthday paradox).